# Get current user name in WordPress theme (3.2)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a WordPress theme, but I can't get the current username. I tried `get_currentuserinfo()` but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any working function to get the username that I can use in the `header.php` template file?

Comment: Define "does not work". What happens?

Comment: returns with null when i logged in.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Did you read the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/), this example work well for me :

```
<?php 
  global $current_user;
  wp_get_current_user() ;
  echo $current_user->user_login;
?>
```